# Node express JS load db contents to Memory always

Tags: node.js, caching, azure-cosmosdb, memcached, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

In my node express APP, I want to load large db content to memory and use it for every API call from the cached memory instead of loading the data from db every time. Is there any way to do this without memory leak in node js? Any library available for this? Also the cached data should re-sync with db once in a day or any edit into the db. I am using Azure Cosmos DB(Mongo driver) with mongoose.

I am aware it will increase the execution size. But I can prevent the application from the memory overflow by the concurrency attack.

Also I want to hear any disadvantage of using like this?

Comment: You should be worried about cache invalidation much more than about memory leaks. Unless you have a proof memory is leaking badly enough to action.

Answer (score 0):

Well what you are describing is a cache,
You can go for an internal one using [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache)
The problem in my view is that you may end with a process occupying a lot of memory
You can go for an infrastructural solution like [Hazelcast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hazelcast-client) or [enter link Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

Hope it helps